# How to make Modal in the center of screen due to absolute position?

Tags: css, modal-dialog

I created a Modal for my framework. I created everything like HTML Codes, CSS Codes & JS Codes ..., It works very good !

My only problem is that I can't make it CENTER & RESPONSIVE ...
This is my CSS Codes for Modal Div :

```
.ji-modal {
    width: 700px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    position: fixed;
    top: 70px;
    left: 325px;
    display: none;
    z-index: 1000005;
}
```

I have read that If your width is fixed & your tag has a Absolute or Fixed Position, You can make it center by giving 50% to left ro right, But It doesn't work too ...

Any Help, Thanks ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To make it responsive, instead try setting the `width` using `%` or `vw` units. Also, to center it horizontally you can use `margin: 0 auto`. Centering it vertically is a little more tricky, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers) for more on that.

Comment: Thanks Oskar, I used 90% for width & Because my DIV is absolute, I put 5% to make it center ...

Answer (score 96):

Setting sizes in percentages is a good option, another option is to use `transform`:

```
.modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

This will move the modal to 50% from top and left, and then adjust it back based upon the dimensions of the modal itself. This isn't ideal for every situation, but it works well in many modal use cases.

Comment: Should note that one situation that this does NOT work is on mobile. Any text fields in the dialog are practically unusable in iOS (something relating to the translation).

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried this:

```
.modal-content{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 50%;
}
```